# Python Serial Read returning strange values

Tags: python, string, serial-port

I have a small python example I got off another website. I am trying to understand how to read from serial using it.

I am sending a message from a FRDM K64f board over serial and the python program reads this but returns a strange values, below is an example of one of them:

YVkJ�ZC

My python code:

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the     device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyACM0',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.isOpen()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the     application.'

input=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input = raw_input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
        out = ''
    # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)

        if out != '':
            print ">>" + out
```

This is my code for the board:

```
int main(){
  Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
  pc.baud(9600);
        while(1){
          char c = pc.getc();
        if((c == 'w')) {  
           pc.printf("Hello");
       }
    }
}
```

The exact return I get is this:

```
Enter your commands below.
Insert "exit" to leave the application.
>> w
>>YVkJ�ZC
>>
```

Comment: What's kind of data do you expect to get from `ser`?

Comment: Hadn't really thought about it like that, I haven't used serial before in python. BUut I was hoping that I could return the value of the string from the board

Comment: I ask because perhaps those "nonsense" strings that you are getting are actually what you get if you interpret the data that you get as a unicode (or whatever encoding) string.

Comment: I have tried encoding the value into a number of different things but no joy so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this.

My declaration of serial didn't seem to be working properly.

Went back to pyserial documentation and declaring my serial like below and using readline() solved the problem.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
```